# Как сделать паузу между отправкой сообщений в vk_api?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

как именно можно организовать паузу между сообщениями в Vk_api?
Пример:
Вот кусок кода.

```
elif message == "1":
                f = open("spam.txt", "r")
                lins = f.readlines()
                for lin in lins:
                    blasthack(id,  lin)
```

Если я дальше пропишу `time.sleep()`, то бот не будет принимать сообщение от других пользователей.
Как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Эх мамкины хацкеры, достаточно перед функцией которая отправляет сообщение добавить time.sleep(время в секундах)

Comment: Что делает функция `blasthack`?

Comment: `def blasthack(id, text):
    bh.method('messages.send', {'user_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': get_random_id(), "keyboard": keyboard.get_keyboard()})`

Comment: `bh = vk_api.VkApi(token="token")`

Comment: Значит в цикле перед `blasthack(id,  lin)` напишите time.sleep()

Comment: Я же писал в вопросе, что уже пробовал `time.sleep()`. И если я так пропишу, то бот не будет видеть сообщение от других пользователей так, как  `time.sleep()` полностью останавливает программу.

Comment: кидай код на pastebin.com , либо ищи способ не делать паузу